# Dynamically create divs Side by Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen so many posts pertaining the titled issue, but non of them worked in my case. 
I want 3 divs to appear in each row but the following code gets each div casted on new line vertically:

***JQuery***

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Image/",
                success: function(data) {
                    var el = $('<div></div>');
                    el.html(data);
                    var imgArr = $('a', el);
                    var images = [];

                    $.each(imgArr, function(i, val) {
                        images[i] = val.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
                        if ($.inArray(images[i].split('.').pop(), ["gif", "png", "jpeg"]) != -1)

                       $('#Panel1').append('<div id="divId"' + i + ' style="height:80px;width:80px;float:left;background-image:url(\'Image/' + images[i] + '\');"></div>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        );
```

***HTML***

```
<body>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="centeredPanel">
        </asp:Panel> 
</body>
```

***CSS***

```
        .centeredPanel
    {
        width:25%;
        height:50%;
        position:absolute;
        left:37.5%;
        top:25%;
    }​
```

imgArr is an array containing images which are retrieved from the folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is panel if panel is your row try html() method in place of append i.e . $('#Panel1').html()

Comment: A Fiddle may help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heck! Actually the problem is with using 'panel' element. As soon as I changed it by 'div' element it fixed my problem.

```
$('#Pardiv').append($("<img style='height:80px;width:80px;float:left;padding:30px;' src= Image/" + images[i] + " />"));
```

where Pardiv is the div containing all the images

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the fact, that divs are by default of the css-display: block, which means, that after each div, there'll start a new line. So I would try to add this to your css:

```
div {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: No thts not the prob. I had replaced div with img element but that didnt work either. $('#Panel1').append($("<img class='image' src= Image/" + images[i] + "></img>"));

Answer (score 0):

In Your CSS add

```
#divId
{
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the divs to be in one line then either use display:inline-block OR float:left;

If you want the divs on different lines, then use display:block;

Demo here (css is inline and you should tweak and put in css classes)

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ke4nhpkm/1/]
```